# How to fill cracks when building wood furniture?

Tags: wood

This is my first thing here, and I'm still an amateur at DIY.

I'm building a raised bed for my daughter.

I'm using wood.

Right now I'm trying to find out what is the best material to fill in imperfections on the wood, and the places of the joins, and even the grain of the wood itself.

My final goal is to use a enamel paint to make "feel" smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good for you for tackling this project.  If you're an amateur and this is your first project, then don't try to be perfect because you will be beating yourself up for no reason.

If you are going to paint the finished project, then the looks don't matter so much.  You can buy wood filler that will fill any gaps and grain.  Force it into any gaps or cracks with a putty knife, and then sand smooth afterwards.   If needed, start with a coarse grain sandpaper (otherwise start with medium) and then progress to fine.   Wood filler can create fine dust, so use a dust mask while sanding.   For panels, I would recommend using MDF as it has a very smooth surface for painting.  Cutting MDF creates a LOT of dust, so always use a mask and remember that it's better to do this outside or with a dust collection system.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for all you suggestions, and yes, I know that this is not going to be perfect :-), but if I use the appropriate techniques / tools it's more likely to be better. Is there any particular brands of wood fillers that you use? I want to get as much info as possible because i'm in Portugal and the terminology will definately be different, but a product/brand name will stay the same, so it will be easier to find here.

Comment: I used the Lepages wood filler.  It's a pretty good product.

Answer (score 0):

If the cracks are large, a catalyzed filler (like car body bondo) often works well.  I think "wood epoxy" is essentially the same product, except that it's tinted grey instead of pink, which may make it easier to stain to the desired hue.